# Saving images into a folder in android?

Tags: android-camera

Hello am using camera in my application.So i want to save Captured images into folder in gallery,floder name must be application name?please suggest me with some Example?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create any folder or file you want. Read this Android article [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):

> Add the Photo to a Gallery When you create a photo through an intent,
>   you should know where your image is located, because you said where to
>   save it in the first place. For everyone else, perhaps the easiest way
>   to make your photo accessible is to make it accessible from the
>   system's Media Provider.
>
> The following example method demonstrates how to invoke the system's
>   media scanner to add your photo to the Media Provider's database,
>   making it available in the Android Gallery application and to other
>   apps.

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code and modify the path where you want to save your image.

```
       mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); Bitmap bitmap =
       mImageView.getDrawingCache();

       String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       File newDir = new File(root + "/app_name/saved_images"); newDir.mkdirs();
       Random gen = new Random(); int n = 10000; n = gen.nextInt(n); String
       fotoname = "photo-" + n + ".jpg"; File file = new File(newDir,
       fotoname); String s = file.getAbsolutePath();
       System.err.print("******************" + s); if (file.exists())
       file.delete(); try { FileOutputStream out = new
       FileOutputStream(file); bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
       90, out); out.flush(); out.close();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved to your folder ",
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      } catch (Exception e) {

       }
```